# Is it possible to find a file with specific text using the dev console or IntelliJ search?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

This would be useful, starting at another company with a new project.

It seems the dev console will show the HTML, not the source file.

In IntelliJ, I have tried the double shift search, and `CTRL-shift+F`.

If there is a Git equivalent, I'll try it too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the dev console"? Are you looking for the `git grep` command at the command line?

Comment: You can try using `Find in Files` feature https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#find_in_project for searching a string inside files.

Comment: If this doesn't work show a screenshot showing the actual result and clarify the expected one.